# bash substring regex matching wildcard

Tags: regex, bash

I am doing bash , i try to test if the substring "world" in the given variable x. I have part of code working. But the other one not working. I want to figure out why

First one is working

```
x=helloworldfirsttime
world=world
if [[ "$x"  == *$world* ]];then
    echo matching helloworld
```

Second one is not working

```
x=helloworldfirsttime
if [[ "$x"  == "*world*" ]];then
    echo matching helloworld
```

How to make second one work without using variable like the 1st method

Can someone fix the second one for me.. thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just remove the quotes:

```
x=helloworldfirsttime
if [[ "$x" == *world* ]]; then
    echo matching helloworld
fi
```

Note that this isn't regex (a regex for this would look something like `.*world.*`).  The pattern matching in bash is described here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Answer (score 3):

```
x=helloworldfirsttime
$ if [[ "$x" == *world* ]]; then echo MATCHING; fi
MATCHING
```

This works because bash's builtin `[[` operator treats the right-hand-side of an `==` test as a pattern:

> When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of  the operator is used as a pattern and pattern matching is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Next time if you want to provide patters with spaces you could just quote it around `""` or `''`, only that you have to place the pattern characters outside:

```
[[ "$x"  == *"hello world"* ]]

[[ "$x"  == *'hello world'* ]]

[[ "$x"  == *"$var_value_has_spaces"* ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shold use without quotes and the `=~` operator.

```
TEXT=helloworldfirsttime
SEARCH=world
if [[ "$TEXT" =~ .*${SEARCH}.* ]]; then echo MATCHING; else echo NOT MATCHING; fi
TEXT=hellowor_ldfirsttime
if [[ "$TEXT" =~ .*${SEARCH}.* ]]; then echo MATCHING; else echo NOT MATCHING; fi
```